¿Como registro las dns de railway en mi dominio de hostinger?
Tengo una app de python alojada en railway y me gustaria asignarle un dominio que tengo en hostinger pero en vez de ponerse el "CNAME" como me lo pide railway se pone "Alias"
Creo que puede deberse al @ que tambien me pide railway

pudiste solucionarlo?, tengo el mismo problema

lo termine delegando cloudflare, pero igual creo que la cosa era porque habia una seccion ya apuntaba a la pagina de hostinguer, trata de encontrar la "ip principal", nosé como explicarlo, luego mando ejemplos
